# Problem Querying data for a whole day from mongoDB using nodeJS

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express

I need some help understanding how Date works with MongoDB. So in MongoDB, I want to retrieve collections for today's date, for example, from today 12:00 am to tonight 11:59 pm.
this is my query in nodeJS

```
const router = express.Router();
router.get("/today", checkAuth, (req, res, next) => {
  today = new Date();
  daysLeftInMonth =
    new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth() + 1, 0).getDate() -
    today.getDate();
  gtDate = new Date(
    today.getFullYear().toString() +
      "-" +
      (today.getMonth() + 1).toString() +
      "-" +
      today.getDate()
  );
  ltDate = new Date(
    today.getFullYear().toString() +
      "-" +
      (today.getMonth() + 1).toString() +
      "-" +
      today.getDate()
  );
  ltDate.setHours(23);
  ltDate.setMinutes(59);
  ltDate.setSeconds(59);
  
  const saleQuery = Sale.find({
    creator: req.userData.userId,
    date: {
      $gt: gtDate,
      $lt: ltDate,
    },
  });
  let fetchedSales;
  saleQuery
    .then((documents) => {
      fetchedSales = documents;
      return Sale.countDocuments();
    })
    .then((count) => {
      res.status(200).json({
        message: "Sales fetched successfully!",
        sales: fetchedSales,
      });
    });
});
```

When I'm running in localhost, this works fine.
[image showing retrieved collections logged to console and in frontend UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcz51.png)

But when I upload my production files to beanstalk, it's only retrieving collections up until 5 pm.
[image showing that when web page is hosted only collections up until 5 are retrieved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBU4l.png)

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Angular CLI: 10.1.7
Node: 12.19.0
OS: win32 x64

Comment: I'm going to hazard a guess that you are in mountain time (UTC-7) and the beanstalk defaults to UTC.

Comment: I didn't know. Great thank you. :) @Joe